# seeking help for an ARIMA "bad value for 'lag' or 'differences' error" using fable package in r

Tags: r, arima, fable-r

I'm running into trouble with the Arima function in the fable package, getting the error in the subject line when I try to run the model. Maybe my dataset has too few observations for arima to work, though auto.arima works fine on the same set. Also, it isn't seasonal- in fact, my observations are four years apart (Presidential election data). Perhaps that's it?

Any help or advice would be welcome.

Here's the dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmr4m3d4ksngurs/PVI%20Data%20arranged%20cols-dates.csv?dl=1

and here's the script:

```
library(tsibble) 
library(lubridate) 
library(fable) 
pvidata<-readr::read_csv("PVI Data arranged cols-dates.csv",col_names = TRUE) 
pvidata$Date<-as.Date(mdy(pvidata$Date)) 
pvidata<-as_tsibble(pvidata,index=Date) 
pvidata<- tidyr::pivot_longer(pvidata,-Date, names_to = "State",values_to="PVI") 
pvidata<-as_tsibble(pvidata,key=State,index=Date) 
fit <- pvidata %>%model(ets = ETS(PVI),arima = ARIMA(PVI))
```

What i get back is:
"Warning message: 50 errors (1 unique) encountered for arima
[50] bad value for 'lag' or 'differences'"

Thanks!

Pete Altman

Answer (score 0):

This error message is uninformative and misleading. This has now been fixed in https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/commit/4b9ae292f940c6e99b05a62cf3e76519fcac67b0 (with the upstream cause fixed in https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/commit/4f7738bcb9b1c2b482937abd50c7e63fb80d4c55).

The issue is due to your construction of the tsibble. By representing your tsibble's index with a Date class, the time granularity of your data is 1 day. However elections are observed every few years, and so the index should be stored as an integer or numeric. A good way to check this is by looking at the tsibble's interval (at the top of the table output):

```r
library(tsibble) 
library(lubridate) 
pvidata<-readr::read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmr4m3d4ksngurs/PVI%20Data%20arranged%20cols-dates.csv?dl=1",col_names = TRUE) 
pvidata$Date<-as.Date(mdy(pvidata$Date)) 
pvidata<-as_tsibble(pvidata,index=Date) 
pvidata<- tidyr::pivot_longer(pvidata,-Date, names_to = "State",values_to="PVI") 
pvidata
#> # A tsibble: 750 x 3 [1461D]
#> # Key:       State [50]
#>    Date       State         PVI
#>    <date>     <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 1962-01-01 Alabama      0.12
#>  2 1962-01-01 Alaska       0.03
#>  3 1962-01-01 Arizona     -0.04
#>  4 1962-01-01 Arkansas     0.07
#>  5 1962-01-01 California   0.01
#>  6 1962-01-01 Colorado    -0.04
#>  7 1962-01-01 Connecticut -0.01
#>  8 1962-01-01 Delaware     0.02
#>  9 1962-01-01 Florida      0.16
#> 10 1962-01-01 Georgia      0.17
#> # … with 740 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The `[1461D]` is the automatically identified interval of the data, which should be `[4Y]`. Setting the date to be an integer fixes this issue:

```r
library(tsibble) 
library(lubridate) 
pvidata<-readr::read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmr4m3d4ksngurs/PVI%20Data%20arranged%20cols-dates.csv?dl=1",col_names = TRUE) 
pvidata$Date<-year(mdy(pvidata$Date)) 
pvidata<-as_tsibble(pvidata,index=Date) 
pvidata<- tidyr::pivot_longer(pvidata,-Date, names_to = "State",values_to="PVI") 
pvidata
#> # A tsibble: 750 x 3 [4Y]
#> # Key:       State [50]
#>     Date State         PVI
#>    <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1  1962 Alabama      0.12
#>  2  1962 Alaska       0.03
#>  3  1962 Arizona     -0.04
#>  4  1962 Arkansas     0.07
#>  5  1962 California   0.01
#>  6  1962 Colorado    -0.04
#>  7  1962 Connecticut -0.01
#>  8  1962 Delaware     0.02
#>  9  1962 Florida      0.16
#> 10  1962 Georgia      0.17
#> # … with 740 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

With the corrected data, the models run without issues:

```r
library(fable) 
#> Loading required package: fabletools
pvidata %>% model(ets = ETS(PVI),arima = ARIMA(PVI))
#> # A mable: 50 x 3
#> # Key:     State [50]
#>    State                ets                   arima
#>    <chr>            <model>                 <model>
#>  1 Alabama     <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(0,1,0)>
#>  2 Alaska      <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(1,0,0)>
#>  3 Arizona     <ETS(A,N,N)>  <ARIMA(0,0,2) w/ mean>
#>  4 Arkansas    <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(1,0,1)>
#>  5 California  <ETS(A,N,N)> <ARIMA(0,1,0) w/ drift>
#>  6 Colorado    <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(0,0,2)>
#>  7 Connecticut <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(1,1,0)>
#>  8 Delaware    <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(0,1,1)>
#>  9 Florida     <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(1,0,0)>
#> 10 Georgia     <ETS(A,N,N)>          <ARIMA(0,0,1)>
#> # … with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For more details you can refer to https://otexts.com/fpp3/tsibble-objects.html and https://pkg.earo.me/tsibble/articles/faq.html